# Is it possible to programmatically change the color of the split actionbar?

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, programmatically-created, splitactionbar

How do I change the color of the split actionbar in code, and not in xml? My user can pick the color of the actionbar, and I would like it so they could also change the color of the split action bar (the actionbar that appears at the bottom of the screen).

I'm implementing splitActionBar using `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in android manifest

so far I'm trying this, but it's not working

```
final int splitBarId = getResources().getIdentifier("split_action_bar", "id", "android");

    final View splitActionBar = findViewById(splitBarId);

    if (splitActionBar != null) {

          splitActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionbar_colors)));

    }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to change the split actionbar color

```
getActionBar().setSplitBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5")));
```

Or use this if you're using support actionbar

```
getSupportActionBar().setSplitBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5")));
```

Source: http://scriptedpapers.com/2014/09/25/android-implement-spilit-action-bar-change-its-background-color/

Answer (score 1):

The framework doesn't provide a way to change it programmatically; however, you can use [`Resources.getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to find the `View` and adjust the background `Drawable` from there.

[The internal id is `split_action_bar`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/screen_action_bar.xml#L52).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    final int splitBarId = getResources().getIdentifier("split_action_bar", "id", "android");
    final View splitActionBar = findViewById(splitBarId);
    if (splitActionBar != null) {
        // Adjust the background drawable
    }
}
```

**Update**

Evidently there's [`ActionBar.setSplitBackgroundDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSplitBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)). Definitely use that callback rather than `Resources.getIdentifier`.

Here's a screenshot of the results:

[image: Example]

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to change anything either

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid It definitely works, I added a screenshot. There's obviously a disconnect somewhere, so you should update your OP and provide more information on how you're adding the split `ActionBar`, etc.

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid Are you using the compatibility library? What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: I'm testing this on Lollipop and I'm not using the compatibility library for the actionbar

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid Are you using a Material based theme or Holo? What is the color code for your `actionbar_colors`?

Comment: I'm using holo, and the color code is #1976D2, I've tried changing the actionbar background using this and it worked

Comment: got it to work, turns out actionbar_colors was screwing something up

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar(); 
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```